# How can I integrate a function which needs to have a matrix calculation first?

Tags: matlab, integral

I am doing my dissertation now. I stuck with a integral. My function is  defined as

`myfun =(exp(t*Q)*V*x)(j);`

where `Q` and `V` are a matrix (n*n), `x` is a vector which elements are 1, then after calculation we get the j_th element of that vector then I need to integrate the function against t.

I want to use the `quad` in the matlab. However the point is that it will report the inner matrix is not the same size. Since A here is not a number ?....

How can I do this. Otherwise I could only write a loop against t itself, which is extremely slow.

Thanks

Comment: this makes no sense. you can't take the (scalar) exponential of a matrix.

Comment: if you mean matrix exponential, you want `expm`, and it would still not be right.

Comment: @Peter: It makes no sense to say "it makes no sense" without seeing the mathematical equation that the OP has implemented. I'm not saying you're necessarily wrong, but it could very well be that OP indeed wants to do an `exp` of each element.

Comment: @yoda: but that is an abuse of the `exp` function actually. In math, you can't call `exp` on a matrix. Matlab happens to implement it as elementwise, but it's not math. Perhaps I'm just grumpy this morning :)

Comment: @Peter: true, you don't do that in math. However, matrix multiplications are a very powerful way of accomplishing certain double sums in math.  And given MATLAB's strength in linear algebra, this would be the most optimal way of doing it. So it could very well be a valid math operation which requires an `exp` of each element, although on the face of it, it _seems_ incorrect. I agree in that nothing is clear from OP's question, and is open to multiple interpretations.

Comment: @Peter  Hi actually I mean to use expm in the Matlab. Actually I want to define function in a way such that the Matrix A is a parameter. Then I want to use the quad to integrate the function. But if I define like expm(t.*A) obviously, matlab would say the dimension does not match .... is there some good way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SUBSREF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/subsref.html) for this (you still neet to loop over all `j`'s, though):

```
 myfunOfT = @(t)(subsref(exp(t*Q)*V*x,struct('type','()','subs',j);
```

This returns the value of the `j`th element of the array at time `t`.